# How to Configure GoogleMock in Visual Studio 2017 After Already Installing GoogleTest?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, googletest, googlemock

I installed the Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn package into my VS 2017 application solution.  This was accomplished by adding a new GoogleTest project to my solution via "Add New Project/Other Languages/C++/Test/Google Test".

The testing works well, but now I am ready to try some mocking with gmock.  So, I installed googlemock.v140.windesktop.static.rt-dyn via NuGet, but I have no idea of how to get it integrated into my test project.

My packages.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="googlemock.v140.windesktop.static.rt-dyn" version="1.7.0.1"  targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="native" />
</packages>
```

... but there are no external dependency header files or .lib files to link to as far as I can see.  I don't know where to go from here. :-)

P.S.  I have posted questions about GoogleTest on Microsoft's C++ forum, but they will not answer these types of questions about GoogleTest even though it was installed via Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some bad Google Test / Google Mock packages available on NuGet, such as the one referenced by this question. The one you want is [the gmock package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/gmock/) authored by Google Inc (version v1.8.1 as of this writing).

Once this package has been installed, your project's `packages.config` should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="gmock" version="1.8.1" targetFramework="native" />
</packages>
```

And you can begin using GMock simply by adding

```
#include "gmock\gmock.h"
```

as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md).

Comment: I had to close & reopen the .sln for GMock to be found even though it showed in my packages.config file.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; The solution for me was renaming the include folder provided with Google Mock package

from:

`packages\googlemock.v140.windesktop.static.rt-dyn.1.7.0.1\build\native\include\gtest`

to

`packages\googlemock.v140.windesktop.static.rt-dyn.1.7.0.1\build\native\include\gmock`

---

I've the exact same situation here (same packages version), but I've solved in another way (since the solution from @R.Evans didn't work).

I've noticed that opening the Google Mock package there is a folder called `gtest` instead of `gmock`, and this name is *hiding* Google Test package. Uninstalling one, you can *see* the other one in the include path.

Moreover all Google Mock headers are using `gmock` as main path for their headers, so with the header folder called `gtest` Visual Studio is reporting tons of errors even in the Google Mock source code.

Comment: Have to do similar after #include "gtest/gmock.h", as gmock.h is using #include "gmock/gmock-actions.h". Some one publish the package without testing it.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon an answer to my own question.  After installing gmock via NuGet, I tried keying **#include "gmock/gmock.h"** in my test project's .cpp just under the **#include "gtest/gtest.h"**.  That did not work.  I looked in the "External Dependencies" folder for any reference to gmock but did not find one.  I was stumped until I replaced **#include "gmock/gmock.h"** with **#include "gtest/gmock.h"**.  There were no errors generated at that point.  I looks like I am on my way to doing some google type mocks.

Comment: #include "gtest\gtest.h"
#include "gtest\gmock.h"

TEST(TestCaseName, TestName) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
  EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
}